# Spring MVC : empty value for form field of type long results in 400 bad request

Tags: java, forms, spring, parsing, spring-mvc

I am trying to submit a form having following fields.

```
private String type;
private long minPrice;
private long maxPrice;
```

when one of the two fields of type `long` is empty, for submission results in 400 Bad request (works fine in case of non empty fields).

Here is an error I get:

> `default message [minPrice]]; default message [Failed to convert
>   property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'long' for
>   property 'minPrice'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""`

As far as I understand that it tries to parse an *empty string* to type `long` or I am wrong?.

Now what should I do so that I can be able to submit this form even if values for fields of type `long` are `null`?

(I am using Spring 4.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use Class "Long" instead of type "long" since primitive type can't have empty values.

Answer (score 2):

Use class [**Long**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Long.html) instead of *primitive type* `long`, you'll be able to check for `null` values so you can process them and avoid the bad request error

```
@RequestMapping(value="/your_path", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String myControllerFunction(
        @RequestParam("minPrice") Long min,
        @RequestParam("minPrice") Long max,
        @RequestParam("type") String type) {

    // your controller code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a different situation, here is a code excerpt :

```
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@PermitAll
@Path("uploadSiteDocument")
void uploadSiteDocument(@FormDataParam("siteId") Long siteId,
                        @FormDataParam("fileTypeId") Long fileTypeId,
                        @FormDataParam("description") String description,
                        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataBodyPart body,
                        @FormDataParam("primaryConnection") Long pcId,
                        @FormDataParam("internalSolution") Long isId)
        throws IOException, RepositoryException;
```

Through Postman this service works ONLY if two last parameters are empty, not with NULL values but empty.

The only two solutions are :

1. to check on the front-end side if those values are null, and to set them as empty string
2. or, to declare those two Long as String types, and the parse them on the back-end side

Solution 2:

```
...@FormDataParam("primaryConnection") **String** pcId,
   @FormDataParam("internalSolution") **String** isId)
```